# How to set Spinner item without onItemSelected getting called

Tags: android, android-spinner

Is it possible to change the selected spinner position to something without having the `onItemSelected` method getting called?

basically what I am trying to do is go back to the previously selected item in the spinner since one of them shows a dialog when selected. When the user hits the back button the spinner still shows that they are on the position that shows the dialog when it has been dismissed.

So is there a way to either keep it from getting called when reverting back using `spinner.setSelection(position)` or is there a way to keep the position that shows the dialog from staying selected?

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
    switch(arg2){
    case 0:

        previousSelection = 1;
        mNavButtonClick.onNavButtonClick(1);

        break;
    case 1:
        previousSelection = 2;
        mNavButtonClick.onNavButtonClick(2);

        break;
    case 2:
        previousSelection = 3;
        mNavButtonClick.onNavButtonClick(3);
        break;
    case 3:
        previousSelection = 4;
        mNavButtonClick.onNavButtonClick(4);
        break;
    case 4:
        previousSelection = 5;
        mNavButtonClick.onNavButtonClick(5);
        break;
    case 5:
                    //this case shows the dialog
        mNavButtonClick.onNavButtonClick(6);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

dialog is shown, user clicks the back button to close dialog and in the `onDismiss` I call

```
spinner.setSelection(previousSelection);
```

to go back to the previous selection but this re-creates the view again which I dont want since I am already on the view I just want to show that I am on the view in the spinner

Comment: Try refreshing the adapter.

Comment: @NarendraDroidWorm that just going to rebuild the list setting the selection position to `0` which really isnt much different from calling `setSelection` on the last position selected

Comment: post your current code, code will describe a lot than words

Comment: @StinePike code added

Comment: so if I am not wrong, your problem is the dialog is showing again after canceling.. right?

Comment: @StinePike no the view of the previous selection is re-created but it does not need to be since the dialog is/was displayed above it so it is still visible when the dialog is dismissed and does not need to be re-created. One of the views does a lot of loading in the background and if the user is on that view I dont want it to load up again unnecessarily

Answer (score 6):

Its very simple!

```
spinner.adapter = adapter
spinner.setSelection(pos) // whatever integer!
spinner.setTag("bug init")
spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) = Unit
        override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, position: Int, p3: Long) {

        if (spinner.getTag().equals("bug init")) {
            spinner.setTag("okay, no more bug")
        }
        else {
            whateverMethod()
        }
}
```

When you put method call in spinner listener, it will very risk that method will executing self because of bug of init still exist in 2020!

So, this is how i solved it!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no way to stop the function being called. BUT, you can choose to NOT execute the code in the function using a simple if (when you use `setSelection`) Check out the accepted answer here:

[Undesired onItemSelected calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21747917/undesired-onitemselected-calls)